# Can SSMS be replaced by VS2010 Express for SQL Development?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering if I can utilize VS2010 Express to create tables, manage/design, and complete queries, or if SSMS will still need to be the go to for this type of work? My googling hasn't provided much detail on utilization of VS2010 for SQL Development alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would still use SSMS.  While you can do some table management from Visual Studio 2010, SSMS will contain a lot more features.  Another disadvantage of managing your tables from Visual Studio is the UI is much slower than using SSMS, especially when you have a large project.